# How to add a line break in a tabularx cell with \addlinespace

Tags: line-breaking, tabularx, seqsplit

Im trying to create a simple table using tabularx. I would like to distanciate the lines in the right cell. I've written the code below that seems to work properly (in the sense I've the expected visual result) but I've a compiling error.

the problem seems to be the command `\addlinespace`. In order to distanciate the lines, I also tried `\makecell[l]{content of the cell here}` but then it seems that I've problem with `\seqsplit` command that doesn't work anymore.

How can I fix my code or how can obtain the same visual effect using a different command? I'm working with Overleaf.

[image: tabularx code]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

    \renewcommand\theadfont{\footnotesize\bfseries}%
    \newcolumntype{K}{>{\footnotesize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

    \begin{table}[ht]
    
        \normalsize\rmfamily\caption{Field DKIM-Signature example}
        \label{table:table-example-field-dkim-signature}
        \centering
        
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=.5\hsize}K>{\hsize=1\hsize}K}
            \toprule
            \thead{Nome campo} & \thead{DKIM-Signature} \\ 
            \toprule
            20191002\_2\_rawplaintext.eml & 
            DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=libero.it; s=s2014; 
            \addlinespace
            \seqsplit{t=1570017017;bh=GuJwjTE60uCl6OYS9j/mGPgR3zd6tej8+oio/XCcU6U=;}
            \addlinespace
            h=Date:From:To:In-Reply-To:References:Subject;          
            \addlinespace
            \seqsplit{b=Mqor4zXLPIhZkXMOnNd8lAX3PK+If8flI+mrYfDF39IskRv8Iuo2qfo2vSIeXKLOzlZLud18uhimRrEP 9OK5RVxpZtT51cekYjBCcKiGwn2dnAPnKdkGTYvVeCaVfurF/qOM08wEdhL6iZ/8ytpqS3M2AG8ZRRZYhSdLKUu8a1/D69dWV9JLKyRlLmb/BxNQDKRwaVTp4IzUcDsEc627yy2l8i5o4iDmLQpjsxX42EJzRRPOoq9W60mekOMjZgLlhmcnMGvqUDwR/hbBunIFWqZkDONAJi9idfJ4nLwYsh2mmUZq7a5d505BfhNRpo7+Zbq1m2cLQjoxE7A39FpB4w==} \\
            \midrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabularx compiling error]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you want? A blank line line does the job, to which you can add some `\vskip`.Note I had to change the coefficients in the table preamble (`\hsize= k\hsize`): the sum of the coefficients has to be equal to the number of `X` columns.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{seqsplit}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

    \renewcommand\theadfont{\footnotesize\bfseries}%
    \newcolumntype{K}{>{\footnotesize\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

    \begin{table}[ht]

        \normalsize\rmfamily\caption{Field DKIM-Signature example}
        \label{table:table-example-field-dkim-signature}
        \centering

        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\hsize=0.67\hsize}K>{\hsize=1.33\hsize}K}
            \toprule
            \thead{Nome campo} & \thead{DKIM-Signature} \\
            \toprule
            20191002\_2\_rawplaintext.eml &
            DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=libero.it; s=s2014;\bigskip

            \seqsplit{t=1570017017;bh=GuJwjTE60uCl6OYS9j/mGPgR3zd6tej8+oio/XCcU6U=;}\bigskip

            h=Date:From:To:In-Reply-To:References:Subject;\bigskip
            %\addlinespace
            \seqsplit{b=Mqor4zXLPIhZkXMOnNd8lAX3PK+If8flI+mrYfDF39IskRv8Iuo2qfo2vSIeXKLOzlZLud18uhimRrEP 9OK5RVxpZtT51cekYjBCcKiGwn2dnAPnKdkGTYvVeCaVfurF/qOM08wEdhL6iZ/8ytpqS3M2AG8ZRRZYhSdLKUu8a1/D69dWV9JLKyRlLmb/BxNQDKRwaVTp4IzUcDsEc627yy2l8i5o4iDmLQpjsxX42EJzRRPOoq9W60mekOMjZgLlhmcnMGvqUDwR/hbBunIFWqZkDONAJi9idfJ4nLwYsh2mmUZq7a5d505BfhNRpo7+Zbq1m2cLQjoxE7A39FpB4w==} \\
            \midrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are also `\smallskip` and `\medskip` which are not as large as `\bigskip`

Comment: @JasperHabicht: Yes, of course. I just wanted the spacing to be obvious at first sight.

Comment: I thought so. I just wanted to add this in case the OP doesn't like the spacing to be that large.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you so much for your support! I finally understand how column sizing works. Basically I've to resolve a linear sistem in which the sum of the size of the columns have to be equal to the number of the columns themselves and the size of the single column has to respect the ratio among columns.

Also thanks for the ```\smallskip``` ```\medskip``` and ```\bigskip``` commands that I didn't know. My understanding is that I also have to add a blank line after these command otherwise nothing happens.

Comment: @MarioSernicola: Yes, determining the coefficients is just a standard exercise on proportionality at the midschool level (or *was*, since programs may have changed  since I was a child).

Comment: @Bernard Sure, thanks a lot, no probems at all in calculating the right size, but now I've a better idea on how organize my tables. I read the documentation but it was not clear as your explanation. Thanks again. Even the aspect of the text inside improved when the size of the columns has been fixed with your suggestion.

Comment: @MarioSernicola. Always glad to feel helpful!